# accessing one window from another

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say we have got 2 windows:
1) the main one;
2) pop uped;

Is it possible to change the DOM of the first window after the second window was closed?
**N.B.** In second window(the pop-up) were some redirection(with full page reload).

**P.S.**
<s>I've put rails tag because trying to do it within rails and probably there's some rails-way-solution for this.</s>

Sorry for my English and thanks in advanced.

Comment: There is no Rails solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes:

```
window.opener.document.write ...
```

Comment: Sorry, i've forgot to manshine that the second window has had redirection with full page reload; I mean `window.opener` becomes the window the current one was redirected from;